# Adding drop shadows to navigation menu?

Tags: wordpress, css, navigation, dropshadow

I want to create drop shadow effect on my wordpress site's navigation menu like this:

[Click here to see the effect](http://www.red-team-design.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/css3-box-shadow.html)

How can i apply it on my .navigation-main class, i tried but nothing happened. here is the header code

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <?php 
        $header_image = get_header_image();
        if( !empty($header_image ) ) { ?>
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name','display' ) );?>" rel="home">
            <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $header_image ); ?>" class="header-image" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width;?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="">
        </a>
        <?php } else {?>
        <div class="site-branding">
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
        </div>
        <?php }?>
        <nav id="site-navigation" class="navigation-main" role="navigation">
            <h1 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'dark_delight' ); ?></h1>
            <div class="screen-reader-text skip-link"><a href="#content" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Skip to content', 'dark_delight' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'dark_delight' ); ?></a></div>

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->
```

**Code to apply effect(this is a snippet from website to which i have provided the link above)**

```
#box 
{
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
  background: #ddd;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 2em 1.5em;
  color: rgba(0,0,0, .8);
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 60px auto;
}


#box:before, #box:after 
{
  z-index: -1; 
  position: absolute; 
  content: "";
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 50%; 
  top: 80%;
  max-width:300px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); 
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);   
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-3deg);    
  -moz-transform: rotate(-3deg);   
  -o-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-3deg);
  transform: rotate(-3deg);
}

#box:after 
{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(3deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(3deg);
  transform: rotate(3deg);
  right: 10px;
  left: auto;
}
```

Comment: You have a live link?

Answer (score 0):

The css is making no reference to the html.  Try changing the #box selector in css to something like .site-header or #masthead

Comment: I know that, i just pasted a snippet from some website and header code is from my site template. I have already tried but it didn't work that's why i am here.